# How to count Integer array elements like char based strlen() in C?

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I would like to count the number of elements in an integer array(sized, like: array[1000]) after input without counting manually while inputting(using `scanf()` which is = number of arguments passed to scanf).Though int arrays are not null terminated as well as `scanf()` cannot be used like `getchar()` or `gets()` and no availale function like `strlen()` for int arrays,is it possible to write a C program to prompt the user to input as many numbers as he wishes and the program will count them(total arguments passed to scanf()) and print the maximum using arrays or pointers?

Comment: What do you mean by sized array?

Comment: C arrays are fixed size. You can use expression `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` or just some constant pre-defined. And no, you can't figure the array's size inside the subroutine.

Comment: not when you pass them to function

Comment: So you want to count the elements without counting them ? ...

Comment: you need to have some kind of termination in your array, but it's not possible for every case

Comment: what kind of input does your program expect (I know that int's, but are they any specific values?)

Comment: sized means not unsized like:arr_[1000] where unsized is like:arr_[] .Though unsized array is invalid in this case

Comment: This program's prime task is to count how many values are passed to scanf()  any

Comment: In that case, count them at the point of entry.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen()` iterates on the character array until the C string termination character (ASCII `\0`) is encountered. So it is `COUNTING` the elements. If you want to do that for an `int` array I guess you could also have a reserved 'terminator' value for your array, make room for it (allocate one more int in your array for the terminator) and implement your own `int_array_len()` similar to `strlen`. However, in your case counting the elements while inputting them seems like a much better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Without having a termination value, you will have to count the inputs as they are made. You could do this by defining a `struct` to hold the array. Your program does not know how many integers you will enter, and this code allocates more memory when the array is full, keeping track of the array size and elements used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAY_STEP 10       // increment in array size

typedef struct {
    int maxlen;             // capacity of array
    int length;             // elements used
    int *array;             // the array pointer
} istruct;

int main(void) {
    istruct intarr = {0};   // empty array
    int i;
    printf ("Enter some integers:\n");
    while (scanf("%d", &i) == 1) {
        if (intarr.length >= intarr.maxlen) {
            intarr.maxlen += ARRAY_STEP;        // increase array size
            intarr.array = realloc(intarr.array, intarr.maxlen * sizeof(int));
            if (intarr.array == NULL) {
                printf("Memory allocation error\n");
                exit (1);
            }
        }
        intarr.array[intarr.length++] = i;
    }

    printf ("You entered:\n");
    for (i=0; i<intarr.length; i++)
        printf ("%-10d", intarr.array[i]);
    printf ("\n");
    if (intarr.array)
        free(intarr.array);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Smart vertion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

{

    double a[100000],mx=0;

    int i,j,c=0;

    printf("Enter as many numbers as you wish . Press Ctrl+D or any character to stop inputting :\n");
    /*for(i=0;i<100000;i++)
        a[i]=0;*/
    for(i=0;i<100000;i++)
    {
        if((scanf("%lf",&a[i]))==1)
            c++;
        //else break;
    }
    for(j=0;j<c;j++)
    {
        if(a[j]>mx) mx=a[j];
    }
    printf("You have inserted %d values and the maximum is:%g",c,mx);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple.

just declare of your desired "initial size". And keep checking if input is a valid integer or not.

`if((scanf("%d",&a[i]))==1)` this would be `true` if and only if the input is a valid integer. hence the moment the input is not an int, it exits the loop. You can count the number of input values within the same loop and also the max values.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>
int main()
{
    int a[100],max = INT_MIN;
    int i,j,count=0;

    printf("Start Entering the integers... Give any non-integer input to stop:\n");
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        if((scanf("%d",&a[i]))==1) {
          count++;
          if(a[i]>max) {
            max = a[i];
          }
        }
        else
          break;
    }
    printf("number of input values: %d;\nThe maximum input value: %d",count,max);

    return 0;
}
```